# Vaadin create connection to SQL Server with MyBatis

Tags: java, sql-server, vaadin, spring-mybatis

I am currently working with the Vaadin Framework and came across a problem where I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`, thinking of this being because of no connection to the SQL Server. I made a user for the sql server called login and the password is hej123456789

Code running while exception is thrown:

```
public class GridUI extends VerticalLayout implements View {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService service;
    Employee employee;

    private void setGrid(){
        Grid<Employee> grid = new Grid<>();
        List employeeList;

        try {
            employeeList = service.findAll(); // here is the exception coming from (Row 32)
            grid.setItems(employeeList);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Label errormsg = new Label(e.toString());
            addComponent(errormsg);
        }

        grid.addColumn(Employee::getId).setCaption("ID");
        grid.addColumn(Employee::getFirstname).setCaption("Förnamn");
        grid.addColumn(Employee::getLastname).setCaption("Efternamn");

        addComponent(grid);
    }
```

Mappers class

```
@Mapper
public interface EmployeeService {
    @Select("SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY id")
    List findAll();

    @Update("UPDATE employee SET firstname=#{fistname} WHERE id=#{id}")
    void update(Employee employee);
}
```

Application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:1433/mydb
spring.datasource.username=login
spring.datasource.password=hej123456789
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.example.UI.GridUI.<init>(GridUI.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator$ClassBasedViewProvider.getView(Navigator.java:336) ~[vaadin-server-8.0.0.jar:8.0.0]
    at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:548) ~[vaadin-server-8.0.0.jar:8.0.0]
    at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator$UriFragmentManager.lambda$setNavigator$567eee34$1(Navigator.java:122) ~[vaadin-server-8.0.0.jar:8.0.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:510) ~[vaadin-server-8.0.0.jar:8.0.0]
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:211) ~[vaadin-server-8.0.0.jar:8.0.0]
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:174) ~[vaadin-server-8.0.0.jar:8.0.0]
    at com.vaadin.server.Page.fireEvent(Page.java:698) ~[vaadin-server-8.0.0.jar:8.0.0]
    at com.vaadin.server.Page.updateLocation(Page.java:1157) ~[vaadin-server-8.0.0.jar:8.0.0]
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI$1.popstate(UI.java:199) ~[vaadin-server-8.0.0.jar:8.0.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:155) ~[vaadin-server-8.0.0.jar:8.0.0]
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:116) ~[vaadin-server-8.0.0.jar:8.0.0]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocation(ServerRpcHandler.java:443) [vaadin-server-8.0.0.jar:8.0.0]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:415) [vaadin-server-8.0.0.jar:8.0.0]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:274) [vaadin-server-8.0.0.jar:8.0.0]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:90) [vaadin-server-8.0.0.jar:8.0.0]
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41) [vaadin-server-8.0.0.jar:8.0.0]
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1464) [vaadin-server-8.0.0.jar:8.0.0]
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:380) [vaadin-server-8.0.0.jar:8.0.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
```

Comment: Please, post the entire stacktrace and (if possible) the complete relevant code that is triggering it, eg: where/how your get your `service` instance. We have no way of imagining why it is thrown based only on your description. It might be because you call your `service` in a bean constructor where your `@Autowired` field was not injected yet, or something else...

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I've updated the post with the information you were talking about. :)

Comment: Is `GridUI` a spring bean as well? I can't tell from your updated code...

Comment: I'ved try to make it a bean without success, and that may be the problem. How do I do it the best way? It should be connected to Microsoft SQL Server, just to let you know. :)

Comment: If it's not a bean, then your service will not be injected, so the NPE is normal. Take a look at the [Vaadin spring tutorial](http://vaadin.github.io/spring-tutorial/) to see how you can mix the 2 together.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, watched a bit an done the @SpringUI, but still no success. https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/building-a-web-ui-for-postgresql-databases

Following this post doesn't help either...

Comment: It's not an issue with the DB connection, it's simply spring related. Besides the `@SpringUI` you'll need our view to be a `@SpringView`. Take a look at [this section](http://vaadin.github.io/spring-tutorial/#_views_and_navigation_with_vaadin_spring) as well

Comment: To the GridUI class, I've added SpringUI and SpringView
To the EmployeeService class, I've added UIScope and SpringComponent

Is this right? Kind of hard for me to get along with this. 
Thanks for you responses

Comment: Add `@Service` on `GridUI` class..that will solve the exception

Comment: @xDotcom That should be right. Nonetheless it also depends on how you setup your application, eg: is it a spring boot app, if not, are did you configure it to use the [`SpringVaadinServlet`](http://vaadin.github.io/spring-tutorial/#_configuring_and_using_vaadin_spring_without_spring_boot), etc. My suggestion would be to start a new demo project following that tutorial to understand how Vaadin and Spring integrate, and then apply what you've learned to your application.

Comment: Still doesn't work, 
{"timestamp":1490788083355,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"com.vaadin.server.ServiceException","message":"java.lang.NullPointerException","path":"/"}

Comment: Where are you getting the NPE? Can you share a [sscce](http://sscce.org) to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Same error / issue here.
My service is not being created even though I have @Autowired the declaration.
My code was working fine as a plain old Spring Boot app.  But now it's a Spring Boot Vaadin project, it's giving me NullPointerExceptions (NPE).

Following on from some of the above suggestions:

Morfic said:

- *Take a look at the Vaadin spring tutorial ...*

But the link is broken:  **http://vaadin.github.io/spring-tutorial/**

Morfic also said:

- *Take a look at this section as well*

But that link is also broken: **http://vaadin.github.io/spring-tutorial/#_views_and_navigation_with_vaadin_spring**